# How can I filter manytomany models?

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-views, many-to-many

I would like to filter my plots objects on the fruit ex.pear. The Inputs are linked via a manytomany to the plots. This is the structure:
[image: foto]

This is the data I get out of it:
[image: foto2]

What i would like to have:
[image: foto3]

result:

[image: foto4]

I tried the following:

```
plots = Plot.objects.filter(fruittype__fruit="Pear")
inputs = Input.objects.filter(plot__in=plots).distinct()
```

This gives me already a close solution for my problem but not what I want.
[image: last]

Now I only would like to filter out the other plots that still show up with apple.

models inputs:

```
class Product (models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    standaard_dosis = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product
class Input (models.Model):
    datum = models.DateField()
    plot = models.ManyToManyField(Plot)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.datum)

class ProductInputs (models.Model):
    input = models.ForeignKey(Inputs, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
    dosis = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        string = str(self.product)
        return string
```

models plots:

```
class Fruit(models.Model):
    fruit = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fruit

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "fruits"


class Fruittype(models.Model):
    fruit = models.ForeignKey(Fruit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fruittype = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fruittype

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "fruitypes"


class Plot(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    fruittype = models.ForeignKey(Fruittype, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.fruittype.fruit) + " | " + self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "plots"
```

Comment: You should show your models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked with:

```
all_inputs=Input.objects.filter(plot__pk__in=plot_ids).distinct().prefetch_related(Prefetch('plot', queryset=Plot.objects.filter(fruittype__fruit__fruit="Pear")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Plot` queryset is not going as deep as it should. I think you should change to something like this (although this is it's a bit of overkill)

```py
plot_ids = Plot.objects.filter(fruittype__fruit__fruit="Pear").values_list('pk', flat=True)
```

or

```py
plot_ids = Plot.objects.filter(fruittype__fruittype="Pear").values_list('pk', flat=True) # I don't know what fruittype is but I guess this would help you
```

Then your "inputs"

```py
inputs = Input.objects.filter(plot__pk__in=plot_ids).distinct()
```

You might wanna try this as well:

```py
from django.db.models import Prefetch
Input.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('plot', queryset=Plot.objects.filter(fruittype__fruit__fruit="Pear"))
)
```

Comment: I've updated my answer although I don't know if it'll work

Comment: Thank tou very much, the combination of both helped me out. I did `all_inputs=Input.objects.filter(plot__pk__in=plot_ids).distinct().prefetch_related(Prefetch('plot', queryset=Plot.objects.filter(fruittype__fruit__fruit="Pear")))
`